# Xamarin cant press "next" button ( "next" button not active)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

This may be one of those stupid questions.but i am new to xamarin and wanted to start creating an app but i cant click the next button when try to create a single view app. I am posting a snapshot and i am really embarrassed i am asking this question.
[image: snapshot]

Comment: There are no target platforms selected (Android and/or OS)... Appears they are deselected and disabled. Is License expired? Xamarin.Andriod and/or Xamarin.iOS installed?

Comment: I think that you have downloaded only the IDE, Xamari Studio app. MonoTouch and MonoDroid seems missing. Look here and download Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Android https://xamarin.com/platform

Comment: This question is duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847640/cant-create-single-view-application-in-xamarin-studio/38010310#38010310.

Answer (score 0):

As for Android you need to have the SDK installed. For the iOS you also need to install latest XCode. That solved the issue for me.